# Como configurar o MySQL no CloudBees

Tags: jboss, cloud, integração

Preciso configurar o MySQL no CloudBees, como posso fazer isso? Alguém que já fez pode me ajudar a configurar essa conexão para ser usada no JBoss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como mencionado pelo usuário **@user6053** a configuração necessária para usar o MySQL no CloudBees consiste na configuração de três arquivos basicamente:

**cloudbees-web.xml** (o arquivo deve ser criado na pasta WEB-INF)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cloudbees-web-app xmlns="http://www.cloudbees.com/xml/webapp/1">
 <!-- Application ID (formatted CB_ACCOUNT/APPNAME) -->
 <appid>geisonsn/webbusam</appid><!-- ID da minha aplicação no CloudBees-->

 <!-- DataSources (use names refererenced via <resource-ref> in WEB-INF/web.xml) -->
    <resource name="jdbc/webbusam" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource">
        <param name="username" value="USUARIO" />
        <param name="password" value="SENHA" />
        <param name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://us-cdbr-cb-east-01.cleardb.net:3306/cb_dbbusam" />

        <!-- Connection Pool settings -->
        <param name="maxActive" value="20" />
        <param name="maxIdle" value="2" />
        <param name="maxWait" value="10000" />
        <param name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
    </resource>
</cloudbees-web-app>
```

**web.xml**

```
    <resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/webbusam</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
 <persistence-unit name="primary">
    <non-jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/webbusam</non-jta-data-source>
    <properties>
       <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
       <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
       <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
    </properties>
 </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**Importante:** A aplicação do exemplo usa o servidor JBoss7.

**Referências**

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693090/how-to-configure-a-mysql-datasource-in-a-cloudbees-java-ee6-application
2. http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/CloudBeesWebXml

Answer (score 2):

1. Crie um arquivo chamado cloudbees-web.xml, existem exemplos na net.
2. Configure-o e configure também o persistence.xml para ficar dessa forma
   java:comp/env/jdbc/NOMEDAAPLICACAO
3. Acrescente isso ao web.xml

    jdbc/lanchoneteonline
    javax.sql.DataSource
    Container